# Simple Question on CruiseControl.Net and MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I have had my first successful build using CC.Net + MSBuild on legacy project. Only took 8 hours.

My newb question is: Where is the output?

My ArtifactDirectory is empty. Where did everything go?

Comment: If it took 8 hours, you might consider looking at TeamCity.

Comment: Well considering I went from no build system at all. Including no subversion repo to something that I get complete build out of.

Comment: I wasn't trying to insult you - getting MSBuild running the first time is a pain. I was just referring to the fact that TeamCity is a lot easier to configure; it's all done through the web interface.

Comment: Oh, no I wasn't insulted. I had no experience with cc.net or msbuild and got all this going within a day so I was pleased.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll logger in the msbuild-task? Did you have the xmllogger publisher?

**EDIT:**
What are you looking for : the results/logs that goes into the dashboard and mail or the website/dll/program you built? 
Could you post your project configuration?

**EDIT2:**
The website/dll you built are located in the outDir you specified in your msbuild task. If you didn't override either the OutDir or the OutputPath property (in your msbuild task or msbuild build script) your website should be located in the WebProject\bin\Release (or Debug)_PublishedWebsites and your dlls should be located in every Project_dir\bin\Release (or Debug).
If you want a common output you need to specify it by overriding OutputPath or BaseOutputPath (see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx ).

Comment: I did specify the ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll. What does the logger have to do with build output.

Comment: In the most recent versions, MSBuild automatically merge msbuild log file. BUt to be interpreted by the dashboard and email-publisher the log must be xml ones (transformed with xslt), the ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll will log the msbuild output in a xml file. the <xmllogger> publisher will automatically merge the different xml files generated during the "prebuild" and "tasks" time. I edited my answer for more information/questions.

Comment: I meant the website/dll. It is an asp.net application in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If your source projects don't compile to custom folders, the code will be located wherever the source was pulled down to on the build box. As Benjamin stated, this will be the workingDirectory specified in the msbuild task.

If you didn't specify a working directory, I believe CruiseControl.net puts code in:

C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\[*Project Name*]\WorkingDirectory